# VLookup Function with NamedRange referenced as String

Tags: excel, vba

I know, there are a couple of similar questions out there, but the more I read the further I seem to get away from my answer.

I have a range (Org) with values for which I want to look up, wheather the values exist in a NamedRange. The name for the NamedRange is built with a concentrate forumla in the cell "D4", it can vary. "Alt" is the range where into I want to wirte the value found in the NamedRange.

The code I have so far is:

```
Dim DS_Att As String
Dim Org As Range
Dim Alt As Range
Dim i As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("DS_Untertyp")

DS_Att = Range("D4").Value
Set Org = Range("E4", Range("E4").End(xlDown))
Set Alt = Org.Offset(0, 1)

For Each i In Alt
i = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(i.Offset(0, -1).Value, Application.Goto(ThisWorkbook.ws1.Range(DS_Att)), 1, False)
Next
```

However, the code does not work (I think there is more then one error).

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: `Application.GoTo` should not be used here - just a reference to the `Range` is all you want.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to make much sense. Why do you select a range in column E, just to offset this to column F instead. Can't you just set your range to column F right away? Also, what is the `i = Worksheetf etc.` line supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @Plutian Thanks for your time! I understand that it does not seem to make much sense, but the point is, that I want to find the values in column E, that don't exist in the NamedRange and leave a blake space there (and do something else later there).
In the i = Worksheet... line I try to use the lookup function to check wheater the value in column E exists in the NamedRange and if so, wirte the value in column F.

Comment: @BigBen I'm sorry, could you be more explicit on how I should reference the range? I can't get it to work.

Comment: `ws1.Range(DS_Att)`.